# How to resize a image in php to fit it into a box of custom size preserving its aspect ratio?

Tags: php

I have a image of 400 by 350 pixels. I have to fit it into a box of 90px by 80px. Whenever I resize it using this code:

```
****************** Create Thumbnails *************************************/
$imageEditor = new ImageEditor($image_name, $path);
$imageEditor->resize(90, 80);
$imageEditor->outputFile($image_name, $paththumbnail);
$imageEditor->outputFile();
**************************************************************************/
```

the output image is smaller in case of height while preserving aspect ratio.
How can i get the exact image resize?

Comment: Your question isn't exactly clear to me. Do you want your thumbnail to have exactly 90 by 80 pixels? That means you will have to cut off approximately 1px on the left and right (80/350*400 = 91.4 > 90). Is that what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$thumb_width = 90;
$thumb_max_height = 80;

$imageEditor = new ImageEditor($image_name, $path);

// get the size of the image
list($width_orig, $height_orig, $image_type) = getimagesize($path . $image_name);

// calculate the aspect ratio
$aspect_ratio = (float) $height_orig / $width_orig;

// calculate new height
$thumb_height = round($thumb_width * $aspect_ratio);

while($thumb_height>$thumb_max_height)
{
    $thumb_width -= 10;
    $thumb_height = round($thumb_width * $aspect_ratio);
}

// resize
$imageEditor->resize($thumb_width, $thumb_height);

$imageEditor->outputFile($image_name, $paththumbnail);
$imageEditor->outputFile();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the simple function to resize your image in php.
Simply you need to pass images size which you want.

```
    /***********************************************************
    *       Custom Image Resize and cropping function
    ***********************************************************/
    function custom_resize($url, $width, $height = null, $crop = null, $single = true) {
        //echo '<br>Width :'.$width.'  Height'.$height;
        //validate inputs
        if (!$url OR !$width)
        return false;

        //define upload path & dir
        $upload_info = wp_upload_dir();
        $upload_dir = $upload_info['basedir'];
        $upload_url = $upload_info['baseurl'];

        //check if $img_url is local
        if (strpos($url, $upload_url) === false)
            return false;

        //define path of image
        $rel_path = str_replace($upload_url, '', $url);
        $img_path = $upload_dir . $rel_path;

        //check if img path exists, and is an image indeed
        if (!file_exists($img_path) OR !getimagesize($img_path))
        return false;

        //get image info
        $info = pathinfo($img_path);
        $ext = $info['extension'];
        list($orig_w, $orig_h) = getimagesize($img_path);

        //get image size after cropping
        $dims = image_resize_dimensions($orig_w, $orig_h, $width, $height, $crop);
        $dst_w = $dims[4];
        $dst_h = $dims[5];

        //use this to check if cropped image already exists, so we can return that instead
        $suffix = "{$dst_w}x{$dst_h}";
        $dst_rel_path = str_replace('.' . $ext, '', $rel_path);
        $destfilename = "{$upload_dir}{$dst_rel_path}-{$suffix}.{$ext}";

        if (!$dst_h) {
        //can't resize, so return original url
        //echo '<br>Width :'.$width.'  Height'.$height;
        $img_url = $url;
        $dst_w = $orig_w;
        $dst_h = $orig_h;
        }
        //else check if cache exists
        elseif (file_exists($destfilename) && getimagesize($destfilename)) {
        //echo '<br>Width :'.$width.'  Height'.$height;
        $img_url = "{$upload_url}{$dst_rel_path}-{$suffix}.{$ext}";
        }
        //else, we resize the image and return the new resized image url
        else {

        // Note: pre-3.5 fallback check 
        if (function_exists('wp_get_image_editor')) {

            $editor = wp_get_image_editor($img_path);

            if (is_wp_error($editor) || is_wp_error($editor->resize($width, $height, $crop)))
                return false;

            $resized_file = $editor->save();

            if (!is_wp_error($resized_file)) {
                $resized_rel_path = str_replace($upload_dir, '', $resized_file['path']);
                $img_url = $upload_url . $resized_rel_path;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
            } else {

                $resized_img_path = image_resize($img_path, $width, $height, $crop);
                if (!is_wp_error($resized_img_path)) {
                    $resized_rel_path = str_replace($upload_dir, '', $resized_img_path);
                    $img_url = $upload_url . $resized_rel_path;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        //return the output
        if ($single) {
        //str return
            $image = $img_url;
        } else {
        //array return
            $image = array(
                0 => $img_url,
                1 => $dst_w,
                2 => $dst_h
            );
        }
        return $image;
    }

 // ****************  Use of these function *********************

 <img src="<?php echo custom_resize($img_url,270,270,true); ?>" />
```