# PHP - Create Thumbnail & maintaining aspect ratio

Tags: php, image, gd, image-resizing

EDIT: This can be easily done in CSS, I didn't know CSS much at the time of writing this

[image]

I have created a thumbnail creator using PHP. The thumbnails generated should be of the same size. But the problem is the use of uploads images having different aspect ratio like landscape or portrait the thumbnail becomes ugly. So I created the picture above for clarification. Whatever be the uploaded image, it will be put into a rectangle image. So the aspect ratio doesn't change and thumbnails will be of the same size. Can anyone pls help me or tell some ideas?

Comment: I think this ressources will be of help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16774521/scale-image-using-php-and-maintaining-aspect-ratio http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180804/how-to-get-the-aspect-ratio-of-an-image

Comment: @LeaveAirykson ok. Let me try...

Comment: @LeaveAirykson Thanks. It worked little bit. Half is done. Now what i need is to put the image obtained in a white rectangle. Can you please help me??

Comment: look at this answer, it may be of help [Add whitespace to image and save file to server](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8758730/3123098)

Comment: Look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6384722/how-to-resize-a-image-in-php-to-fit-it-into-a-box-of-custom-size-preserving-its this might help you.

Comment: While CSS is a cool tool, I would never use it for thumbnail creation unless it's a dynamic image you could resize. The reason being is a "thumbnail" should be a small image in filesize. CSS is just going tell the browser to downscale the large version, which means large file sizes which could break continuity of pages loading.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
define('THUMBNAIL_IMAGE_MAX_WIDTH', 150);
define('THUMBNAIL_IMAGE_MAX_HEIGHT', 150);

function generate_image_thumbnail($source_image_path, $thumbnail_image_path)
{
    list($source_image_width, $source_image_height, $source_image_type) = getimagesize($source_image_path);
    switch ($source_image_type) {
        case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
            $source_gd_image = imagecreatefromgif($source_image_path);
            break;
        case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
            $source_gd_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source_image_path);
            break;
        case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
            $source_gd_image = imagecreatefrompng($source_image_path);
            break;
    }
    if ($source_gd_image === false) {
        return false;
    }
    $source_aspect_ratio = $source_image_width / $source_image_height;
    $thumbnail_aspect_ratio = THUMBNAIL_IMAGE_MAX_WIDTH / THUMBNAIL_IMAGE_MAX_HEIGHT;
    if ($source_image_width <= THUMBNAIL_IMAGE_MAX_WIDTH && $source_image_height <= THUMBNAIL_IMAGE_MAX_HEIGHT) {
        $thumbnail_image_width = $source_image_width;
        $thumbnail_image_height = $source_image_height;
    } elseif ($thumbnail_aspect_ratio > $source_aspect_ratio) {
        $thumbnail_image_width = (int) (THUMBNAIL_IMAGE_MAX_HEIGHT * $source_aspect_ratio);
        $thumbnail_image_height = THUMBNAIL_IMAGE_MAX_HEIGHT;
    } else {
        $thumbnail_image_width = THUMBNAIL_IMAGE_MAX_WIDTH;
        $thumbnail_image_height = (int) (THUMBNAIL_IMAGE_MAX_WIDTH / $source_aspect_ratio);
    }
    $thumbnail_gd_image = imagecreatetruecolor($thumbnail_image_width, $thumbnail_image_height);
    imagecopyresampled($thumbnail_gd_image, $source_gd_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $thumbnail_image_width, $thumbnail_image_height, $source_image_width, $source_image_height);

    $img_disp = imagecreatetruecolor(THUMBNAIL_IMAGE_MAX_WIDTH,THUMBNAIL_IMAGE_MAX_WIDTH);
    $backcolor = imagecolorallocate($img_disp,0,0,0);
    imagefill($img_disp,0,0,$backcolor);

        imagecopy($img_disp, $thumbnail_gd_image, (imagesx($img_disp)/2)-(imagesx($thumbnail_gd_image)/2), (imagesy($img_disp)/2)-(imagesy($thumbnail_gd_image)/2), 0, 0, imagesx($thumbnail_gd_image), imagesy($thumbnail_gd_image));

    imagejpeg($img_disp, $thumbnail_image_path, 90);
    imagedestroy($source_gd_image);
    imagedestroy($thumbnail_gd_image);
    imagedestroy($img_disp);
    return true;
}

generate_image_thumbnail('original_image.jpg', 'thumb_image.jpg'); //call the function
```

with that code, you will get something similar to

[image]

Comment: In line 37, it needs to be $img_disp = imagecreatetruecolor(THUMBNAIL_IMAGE_MAX_WIDTH, THUMBNAIL_IMAGE_MAX_HEIGHT); (replace second parameter by THUMBNAIL_IMAGE_MAX_HEIGHT).

Comment: this does not work with a PNG transparent image with black text, creates a BLACK image thumb.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the source code of my **[Mr Thumb Image Resizing](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/5692-PHP-Resize-images-keeping-the-original-size-proportion.html)**. :)

```
public function proportion($max_width, $max_height) {

    if (!( $this->halt )) {
        if ($this->image['extension'] == 'gif') {
            $this->image['ratio'] = ( $this->image['width'] > $this->image['height'] ) ? $max_width / $this->image['width'] : $max_height / $this->image['height'];
            if ($this->image['width'] > $max_width || $this->image['height'] > $max_height) {
                $new_width = $this->image['width'] * $this->image['ratio'];
                $new_height = $this->image['height'] * $this->image['ratio'];
            } else {
                $new_width = $this->image['width'];
                $new_height = $this->image['height'];
            }
            $this->image['composite'] = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
            imagecopyresampled($this->image['composite'], $this->image['render'], 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $this->image['width'], $this->image['height']);
            $this->image['colorcount'] = imagecolorstotal($this->image['render']);
            imagetruecolortopalette($this->image['composite'], true, $this->image['colorcount']);
            imagepalettecopy($this->image['composite'], $this->image['render']);
            $this->image['transparentcolor'] = imagecolortransparent($this->image['render']);
            imagefill($this->image['composite'], 0, 0, $this->image['transparentcolor']);
            imagecolortransparent($this->image['composite'], $this->image['transparentcolor']);
        } else {
            $this->image['ratio'] = ( $this->image['width'] > $this->image['height'] ) ? $max_width / $this->image['width'] : $max_height / $this->image['height'];
            if ($this->image['width'] > $max_width || $this->image['height'] > $max_height) {
                $new_width = $this->image['width'] * $this->image['ratio'];
                $new_height = $this->image['height'] * $this->image['ratio'];
            } else {
                $new_width = $this->image['width'];
                $new_height = $this->image['height'];
            }
            $this->image['composite'] = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
            imagecopyresampled($this->image['composite'], $this->image['render'], 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $this->image['width'], $this->image['height']);
        }
    } else {
        echo 'Execution halted!';
    }
}
```

Comment: I am new to PHP. Can you pls tell me how to call this function, where to put the filename, destination like that??

Comment: @user3392772 Click the link. Look at the example of it's use under `example.php` http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/28565.html Changing `$image` variable to `$image = $_GET['i']` will allow you to link images in a basic HTML tag like `<img src="example.php?i=images/myimage.jpg" alt="My Image" />` You can also change the max width and height variables to queries to define width/height on the fly `<img src="example.php?i=images/myimage.jpg&w=200&h=300" alt="My Image" />`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that might help you out. You tell it the width you want to maintain, and it will preserve the aspect ratio while also producing a thumbnail.

```
public static function makeThumb($src, $dest, $desired_width, $format = 'image/jpeg')
{
    /* read the source image */
    $source_image = null;
    if($format == 'image/jpeg')
    {
        $source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
    }
    else if($format == 'image/png')
    {
        $source_image = imagecreatefrompng($src);
    }

    $width = imagesx($source_image);
    $height = imagesy($source_image);

    /* find the "desired height" of this thumbnail, relative to the desired width  */
    $desired_height = floor($height * ($desired_width / $width));

    /* create a new, "virtual" image */
    $virtual_image = imagecreatetruecolor($desired_width, $desired_height);

    imageAlphaBlending($virtual_image, false);
    imageSaveAlpha($virtual_image, true);

    /* copy source image at a resized size */
    imagecopyresampled($virtual_image, $source_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $desired_width, $desired_height, $width, $height);

    /* create the physical thumbnail image to its destination */
    if($format == 'image/jpeg')
    {
        imagejpeg($virtual_image, $dest);
    }
    else if($format == 'image/png')
    {
        imagepng($virtual_image, $dest);
    }
}
```

Comment: @lewisd I tried this one. Its only resizing the image, not according to the one i have shown in the picture

Answer (score 0):

Use ImageMagick API .Check out this

```
define('THUMB_WIDTH', 60);
define('THUMB_HEIGHT', 80);
define('MAGICK_PATH','/usr/local/bin/');

function makeThumbnail($in, $out) {
    $width = THUMB_WIDTH;
    $height = THUMB_HEIGHT;
    list($w,$h) = getimagesize($in);

    $thumbRatio = $width/$height;
    $inRatio = $w/$h;
    $isLandscape = $inRatio > $thumbRatio;

    $size = ($isLandscape ? '1000x'.$height : $width.'x1000');
    $xoff = ($isLandscape ? floor((($inRatio*$height)-$width)/2) : 0);
    $command = MAGICK_PATH."convert $in -resize $size -crop {$width}x{$height}+{$xoff}+0 ".
        "-colorspace RGB -strip -quality 90 $out";

    exec($command);
}
```

Refer to this link - http://coffeeshopped.com/2009/01/creating-image-thumbnails-using-php-and-imagemagick or https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.imagick.php

Comment: I called it using the function makeThumbnail('test.jpg','new.jpg');
But nothing is happening

Comment: You have to install ImageMagick. Check this - http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.setup.php

Comment: What about installing it in sever? is it possible?

Comment: Yes, it is definately possible